# how to get height of the item in a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I am using a customadapter and overriding the getView() method. In this method I call view.getHeight() which returns 0. I would like to find out the height (in pixel) of each item in the listview. And find out where it is on the screen. So If I have 10 items in the list view is it possible to find out where the 5th item position on the screen(in pixel) I would like to find out the y of the item. top left corner.

```
CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.rowlayout,mydizi);
    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    lv.addHeaderView(header);


        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        View viewList = lv.getChildAt(5 - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        viewList.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use something like the ViewTreeObserver.  Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501840/get-actual-height-of-view) question's response.  You can place a block similar to this in your onCreate method.  If a view is returning a value of 0 it is most likely that your are calling the view method too early in the activity lifecycle (ie before the screen objects are mapped out and able to be measured).

Answer (score 0):

For a given VISIBLE row nPosition in list mList, you can get the location of the view via:

```
// find the position of the source and destination accounts ListView rows
int[] location = {0,0};

View viewList = mList.getChildAt(nPosition - mList.getFirstVisiblePosition());
viewList.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

but you'll likely need to do this from outside your getView(), i.e. after the list is populated.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I couldnt get it worked. I just added the code where I put the code but it generates error on the line viewList.getLocationOnScreen(location); nullpointerexception.