# Calculating the height of each row of a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to make the background of a ListView scroll with the ListView. I am basing my approach on this class in [Shelves](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/view/ShelvesView.java), but while in Shelves everything has the same height, I can't make the same guarantee.

I have an activity like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
            items.add("Hello " + i);
        }
        CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, items);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Where CustomArrayAdapter is:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private List<Integer> mHeights;

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //snip
    }
}
```

What I want to do is populate mHeights in the adapter with heights of the rows of the view.

My main attempt was to do this, in getView():

```
if(row.getMeasuredHeight() == 0) {
    row.measure(
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}
mHeights.set(position, row.getMeasuredHeight());
```

I've tried several ways to do this, but I can't get anything to work.

In `getView`, if I call `getHeight()` I get a return value of 0, while if I call `getMeasuredHeight()`, I get something non-zero but not the real height. If I scroll down and then up again (taking one of the rows out of view) `getHeight() == getMeasuredHeight()` and both have the correct value. If I just update mHeights in getView as I go (by saying `mHeights.set(position, row.getHeight()`); it works - but only after I've scrolled to the bottom of the ListView. I've tried calling row.measure() within the getView method, but this still causes `getHeight()` to be 0 the first time it is run.

My question is this: how do I calculate and populate mHeights with the correct heights of the rows of the ListView? I've seen some similar questions, but they don't appear to be what I'm looking for. The `ViewTreeObserver` method seems promising, but I can't figure out how to force calls to getView() from it (alternately, to iterate the rows of the ListView). Calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` causes an infinite (although non-blocking) loop.

1. [Get Actual Height of View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501840/get-actual-height-of-view)
2. [how to get height of the item in a listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671165/how-to-get-height-of-the-item-in-a-listview)

This is related to my previous question on the subject, which seems to have missed the point: [ListView distance from top of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111847/listview-distance-from-top-of-the-list)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. It's was a bit tricky, but it works.

The subtlety was getting layout parameters when they are known. As I learned, `getView()` is returning the view for the initial time, so of course it can't have a height yet  - the parent doesn't know about the row yet (since `getView()`'s job is to inflate it), so we need a callback.

What might that callback be? It turns out, as best I can tell it's the `OnLayoutChangeListener()` for the row's view. So in `getView()` in my custom `ArrayAdapter`, I added a callback for `onLayoutChanged` like so:

```
row.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,
            int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        ref.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        Log.d("CustomArrayAdapter", "onLayoutChange(" + position + "): height " + (bottom - top));
        mHeights.set(position, (bottom - top));
        if(position > 0) {
            mDistances.set(position, bottom - top + mDistances.get(position-1) + ((ListView)parent).getDividerHeight());
        }
        holderRef.distanceFromTop = mDistances.get(position);
        Log.d("CustomArrayAdapter", "New height for " + position + " is " + mHeights.get(position) + " Distance: " + mDistances.get(position));
    }
});
```

Here, `row` is the view to be returned by `getView()` in the adapter, `mHeights` is a list of the height of each element of the `ListView`, and `mDistances` is a list of the distance from the top of the list view in pixels - the real thing that I wanted to calculate (that is, if you laid out the entire list view end to end, how far from the top element i would be from the top). All of these are stored within the custom `ArrayAdapter`. These lists are initialized to zeroes.

Adding this callback allowed me to calculate the height of the view.

My goal was to have a ListView that has a background that scrolls with the list. If anyone is interested, I put the code up on GitHub if anyone would like to review it: https://github.com/mdkess/TexturedListView

Comment: Heads up:  Looks like addOnLayoutChangeListener() is only available in API Level 11 and up.  Anyone have a method that works with earlier versions of Android?

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4406090/616561) SO answer should work for developers who also want to support API level < 11.

Basically, instead of adding a `View.onLayoutChnageListener` to your view, you can set a `OnGlobalLayoutListener` on your view's `ViewTreeObserver`.