# Repeating drawable in List View cell

Tags: android, listview, drawable, repeat

I am trying to build a ListView with a ribbon, much like what Path has done, can be seen here: https://lh3.ggpht.com/Nyw96YFpuXHgQRWOA8-iz5EQLcz71sGZlbgw3ALdaKQDdzBkcdBckDX-KA8dFDK4DA8z=h900-rw

I know the bitmap resource with the attribute 'tileMode="repeat"' does work on a single layout, but when I try to use this to create a ListView cell, the drawable does not repeat in the Y direction, it just renders the drawable once.

The ribbon resource (height: 1px) ribbon.xml:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/ribbon_orig"
android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

Cell layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ribbon"
        android:background="@drawable/ribbon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ribbon_x_offset"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is this even possible?

The only way I found to do this is to specifically define the layout_height, which I am really trying to avoid.

Comment: Have you tried using 9-patch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

In the "getView" function of the ArrayAdapter for the ListView. The height (and width) are not calculated yet, therefore "match_parent" on the LinearLayout to show the ribbon is useless.

The fix I have right now is to "addOnLayoutChangeListener" on the inflated view and then immediate take the listener off and set the LinearLayout to the correct height.

This other stack overflow question gave me the idea:
[Calculating the height of each row of a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131948/calculating-the-height-of-each-row-of-a-listview)