# TranslateAnimation - animation works only after the second time

Tags: android, animation

I used some code I found for a sliding panel, and basically it works but has a small issue.

The animation doesn't work on the first time the panel gets open.

here's the code for the animation:

```
    TranslateAnimation anim = null;


    m_isOpen = !m_isOpen;

    if (m_isOpen) {
        setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        anim = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, getHeight(), 0.0f);
    } else {
        anim = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, getHeight());
        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
              public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                   setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }

              public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                   // not needed
              }

              public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                   // not needed
              }
        });

    }

    anim.setDuration(300);
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
    startAnimation(anim);
```

why on the first I open the panel there's no animation but all the other ones there is?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? Try to debug it of put some logs. Mabye it starts when your panel isn't visible yet or is creating it's view?

Comment: It doesn't work. only after it opens for the first time, the animations works for both opening and closing

Comment: I found a kind of solution: instead of set the visibility of the panel to GONE, I just close the panel when the app starts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When are you calling this? It is probably only doing it "after the first time" because the panel has not been rendered yet when you first call it, and `getHeight()` is returning 0. Try waiting until `getHeight()` has a value and start the animation then. You can also try to hardcode the value to something just to test that my theory is right.

Comment: you right. I tried with `getMeasuredHeight()` which I thought would give the height before rendering, but apparently it isn't. is there a better solution than the one I wrote in the comment above?

Comment: I don't know your context (presumably this is a widget?), if you're doing a custom View, you can check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864331/how-to-get-an-android-widgets-size-after-layout-is-calculated) for a suggested alternative.

Comment: this answer to this question doesn't work for my scenario. `getHeight()` is called when the application is up and running.

Comment: well, I think the only solution is to set the animation with a fixed number instead of `getHeight`

Comment: Hopefully it's a known quantity that you can set on a <dimens> constant.

Comment: Downvoted since "try waiting until getHeight() has a value" doesn't make sense until you suggest a solution on _how_ to wait.

Comment: The easiest way to wait for a component to be ready is to use the [post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) method.

Comment: Just to elaborate on what dmon said, if the height is set to a specific value in the XML, then you can use the following code to get it:                   `int theLayoutHeight = theView.getLayoutParams().height;
      
      if (theLayoutHeight > 0)
      {
        theViewHeight = theLayoutHeight;
      }`

Answer (score 0):

The way I made that code working:

```
final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.panel);
viewGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
final ViewTreeObserver treeObserver = viewGroup.getViewTreeObserver();

if (treeObserver.isAlive()) {
    final OnPreDrawListener l = new OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            treeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, viewGroup.getHeight(), 0.0f);
            anim.setDuration(1000);
            anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
            viewGroup.startAnimation(anim);

            return false;
            }
        };
    treeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(l);
}
```

That is it in its essence. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one view that you are trying to animate, then you can write the animation in XML like so:

```
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        (or)    
android:toYDelta="-100%"  
android:duration="300"/>
```

This way, you don't need to use `getHeight()`. The Java portion then looks like this:

```
    final View flashTitle = findViewById(R.id.flash_title);
    Animation slideDownOnscreen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation
            (this,  R.anim.slide_down_onscreen);
    flashTitle.setAnimation(slideDownOnscreen);
    flashTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Alternatively, if you need to animate several views in conjunction, do the above with the first view, and animate the subsequent views in a `post runnable` so that `getHeight()` returns the correct height of the first view, like so:

```
    flashTitle.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("NOTE    flashTitle height: "+flashTitle.getHeight());
            Animation slideDown = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,
                    -flashTitle.getHeight(),0);
            slideDown.setDuration(300);
            flashLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            flashLine.startAnimation(slideDown);
            //(or)flashLine.animate().translationYBy(flashTitle.getHeight()).setDuration(300);
        }
    });
```

You would also need to add the `accelerate_interpolator` as Android's default is `accelerate_decelerate_interpolator`.

Comment: If you also need to move a view that's currently visible out of the way, you'll need to calculate the height in `onCreate()`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10134260/1902059) on how.

Answer (score 0):

you can Use Delay for work it

```
 TranslateAnimation animate1 = new TranslateAnimation(
                    0,                 // fromXDelta
                    0,                 // toXDelta
                    0,  // fromYDelta
                    binding.saveCardview.getMeasuredHeight());                // toYDelta
                animate1.setDuration(500);
                animate1.setFillAfter(true);
                binding.saveCardview.startAnimation(animate1);

                final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Do something after 100ms
                        binding.saveCardview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        TranslateAnimation animate2 = new TranslateAnimation(
                                0,                 // fromXDelta
                                0,                 // toXDelta
                                binding.carCardview.getHeight(),  // fromYDelta
                                0);                // toYDelta
                        animate2.setDuration(1000);
                        animate2.setFillAfter(true);
                        binding.carCardview.startAnimation(animate2);
                    }
                }, 500);
```