# Error inflating class android.widget.EditText due to android:background="@drawable/bg_login"

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-relativelayout, layout-inflater, inflate-exception

I am having this issue only with Android L GenyMotion emulator. The following layout file throws an error :  Error inflating class android.widget.EditText
Now when I remove android:background="@drawable/bg_login" the error goes of. This is very strange. I tried a lot googling for the solution but in vain. This issue does not occur on other devices running lower versions of android.

Layout File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_login"
    tools:context="com.example.activities.LoginActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:hint="username"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:background="@drawable/graphic_input"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/password">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/graphic_input"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:hint="password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_above="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="164dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="235dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="77dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_login"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Exception:

```
Process: com.example, PID: 1882
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.activities.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.EditText
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.EditText
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:49)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:49)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1508952 byte allocation with 56504 free bytes and 55KB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:634)
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:65)
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:61)
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:57)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:49)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: So what is `bg_login`? bitmap/xml...

Comment: png file with the size of 348 kb

Comment: 1) Post the logcat of the exception. 2) It's nice that the png *file* is 348 kB. Compute the real size in memory like this: width*height*4/1024 (kB). I suspect the image is too big, can you replace it with a gradient or another xml drawable?

Comment: I have added the logcat. Yes I am able to replace with a smaller image. Looks like the image was too big.

Comment: I am using http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html method to resize my image to fit the background.How do i get int reqWidth, int reqHeight parameters ?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27575597/2444099