# Android Expandable RecyclerView different Card height

Tags: java, android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a RecyclerView that contains a list of cards, each of which expand into child cards.
Each card has different text. I want that when the user clicks on a child card, it will expand to show the text inside. The expansion height is based on how much text the card contains.

I tried to measure the target height by using:

```
view.Measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
```

And then expanding the card to the Measured Height (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation)).
However, it gives the same Measured Height to all of the cards.

Here is my code, which is based on [this](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view) (more specifically the [Xamarin version](https://github.com/frankcalise/XamDroid.ExpandableRecyclerView)):

This is the main Adapter, which creates and binds the parent and the child cards:

```
public class HalachaExpandableAdapter : ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<HalachaParentViewHolder, HalachaChildViewHolder>, View.IOnClickListener
{
    LayoutInflater _inflater;
    bool expand;
    int targetHeight;
    bool wave = false;

    public HalachaExpandableAdapter(Context context, List<IParentObject> itemList) : base(context, itemList)
    {
        _inflater = LayoutInflater.From(context);
    }

    public override void OnBindChildViewHolder(HalachaChildViewHolder childViewHolder, int position, object childObject)
    {
        var halachaChild = (HalachaChild)childObject;
        childViewHolder.halachaChildTitle.Text = halachaChild.Title.ToString();

        targetHeight = childViewHolder.halachaChildCard.Height;
        childViewHolder.halachaChildCard.LayoutParameters.Height = 100;
        childViewHolder.halachaChildCard.SetOnClickListener(this);
        expand = childViewHolder.expand;

    }

    public override void OnBindParentViewHolder(HalachaParentViewHolder parentViewHolder, int position, object parentObject)
    {
        var halacha = (HalachaItem)parentObject;
        parentViewHolder._halachaTitleTextView.Text = halacha.Title();
        parentViewHolder._halachaContentTextView.Text = halacha.Content;
        if (halacha.ChildObjectList.Count == 1)
            wave = true;
    }

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        if (v.Height == 100)
        {
            AnimationCollapse anim = new AnimationCollapse(v, targetHeight, 100);
            anim.Duration = 300;
                            v.StartAnimation(anim);

            expand = false;
        }
        else
        {
            AnimationCollapse anim = new AnimationCollapse(v, 100, v.Height);
            anim.Duration = 300;
                            v.StartAnimation(anim);

            expand = true;
        }
    }

    public override HalachaChildViewHolder OnCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup childViewGroup)
    {
        var view = _inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.halachotListItem, childViewGroup, false);
        return new HalachaChildViewHolder(view);
    }

    public override HalachaParentViewHolder OnCreateParentViewHolder(ViewGroup parentViewGroup)
    {
        var view = _inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.halachotListHeader, parentViewGroup, false);
        wave = false;
        return new HalachaParentViewHolder(view);
    }
}
```

I think this is where the code is needed to be done, but if you need some of the other code of the other classes, I will gladly post them. You can also look at the links above for reference to how this works.

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: You set the fix height 100 to every child.

Comment: I know that. That is the start height. I want to set it to wrap content when the card is clicked. How do I do that?

Comment: try to set measure height of childview to it.

Comment: That is what I did, as stated in the question. However, it measured the same height for all of the childviews.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem.
I needed to change the way I measured the view's wrap_content height to this:

```
v.Measure(MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(v.Width, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly), MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost));
```

The rest is the same.
Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255446/accurate-way-to-determine-the-measured-height-of-a-view-even-before-it-changed) post.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know why do you want to find the height of the card , instead you can just wrap the child cards height to that of text and make child card invisible , as soon as user click a card , child card s visiblity will be turned to visible and card wih its text with the same height will appear !

Comment: I wanted to show the child cards, only with a small height, and when the user clicks on the card, it expands to wrap the content. That's what made it tricky. See my final answer. Thanks anyways.