# Remove OnScrollChangedListener from ViewThreeObserver

Tags: android, listener

I have this code:

```
ViewThreeObserver observer = my_view.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

    @Override
public void onScrollChanged() {
        if(condition) {
        //do something
        }
    }
});
```

Now I would remove listener on observer if condition is verified. 
I've try with:

```
 observer.addOnScrollChangedListener(null);
```

But I get an error that claim "ViewThreeObserver is not alive". What does it mean, and how I could remove listener correctly?

Answer (score 3):

`observer` is a long-lived reference which has no guarantee to be valid for the lifetime of the view. Instead you can just call `getViewTreeObserver` on your view again and remove the listener (use removeOnScrollChangedListener as Ahmad mentioned).

```
my_view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnScrollChangedListener(this);
```

Although this is a short-lived call, there is a potential of it being not alive so you could check isAlive on it beforehand (never experienced this myself).

You can also use `isAlive` on `observer` if you wanted to (most likely will not be alive) and use that to remove the listener. If `observer` is not alive you will need to call `getViewTreeObserver` anyway.

Quote for [getViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getViewTreeObserver%28%29)

> Returns the ViewTreeObserver for this view's hierarchy. The view tree
>   observer can be used to get notifications when global events, like
>   layout, happen. The returned ViewTreeObserver observer is not
>   guaranteed to remain valid for the lifetime of this View. If the
>   caller of this method keeps a long-lived reference to
>   ViewTreeObserver, it should always check for the return value of
>   isAlive().

I've seen many different variations of this here are a few:

- [Without checking isAlive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10134260/3286163)
- [Checking isAlive on short-lived call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301092/3286163)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ViewTreeObserver#removeOnScrollChangedListener(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#removeOnScrollChangedListener%28android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener%29) instead of setting the listener to null.

> I get an error that claim "ViewThreeObserver is not alive"

It's recommended that you check with [`ViewTreeObserver#isAlive()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#isAlive%28%29) if the `ViewTreeObserver` is alive or not before removing the listener.