# ListFragment with a custom view hierarchy results with zero width / height children in onViewCreated

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-inflate

I'm inflating `View` for [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) with:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

In `public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)` I'm checking the view children's width/height and it seems that they are always 0. **Why?**

This is my `fragment_home.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_map_h" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/event_height"
        android:gravity="center">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/location_icon_grey"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <com.gigaset.location.ui.custom.TextViewMuseo
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/home_no_events"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/home_latest_pos_h"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Views` will not take on any size until it is laid out on the screen. Aka, usually after `onResume()`.  If you wish to obtain it's measurements when known, you can use a layout listener. For more details and an example: [Android - get height of a view before it´s drawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575706/android-get-height-of-a-view-before-it%C2%B4s-drawn)