# How to get ListItem height of a listview (CustomAdapter used)?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am using custom adapter for a listview and i need to get the listitem height for displaying the listview in a scrollview. I tried to do that in a normal listview with simple adapter. I am able to get the adapter using [listView.getAdapter()] but in case of customadapter unable to get the adapter or height of the listitem. How can i make it possible. And also unable to have listitem click.

This is my reffered link for listview in scrollview:
[Click here](http://nex-otaku-en.blogspot.in/2010/12/android-put-listview-in-scrollview.html)

The code of the adapter i have used is:

[CustomAdapter-Code](http://pastebin.com/cZjTPZ1Y)

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864331/how-to-get-an-android-widgets-size-after-layout-is-calculated), maybe this helps for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [Null pointer exception]

I guess change here,

```
int height = convertView.getHeight(); >> int height = vi.getHeight();
```

p.s. just guess, sorry for my bad if it doesn't help