# How to get Home Screen Widget Size

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

In android 4.2, there is a new callback called onWidgetOptionChanged() in which a bundle containing the widget size information is passed back. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider

My question is, how do we get the widget size prior to android 4.2?

I need to set a picture to an ImageView in the widget but I need to know the size of the ImageView / Widget to scale the picture accordingly.

Also, the layout used for the widget changes depending on its size. Without onWidgetOptionChanged(), how does one know when to use a different layout depending on the size of the widget?

Comment: Check [if this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2864490/1777090)

Comment: @PurpleDroid Ive looked at that link before. Unfortunately I cant get the reference to the ImageView to use an ImageView.postDelayed(int) method. Creating a custom ImageView is also out of the question due to the limitation of RemoveViews in Home Screen Widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that you cannot get current widget size on android before 4.2. Only preconfigured widget size through `android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager#getAppWidgetInfo`.